# Why do people put up with Alan?

Tags: plot-explanation, two-and-a-half-men

I have watched the series of **Two and a Half Men** two times now till the latest episode, but can't understand why either Charlie or Walden just don't kick Alan out? I mean it is a bit cruel but they are shown to put up with him even though he gets up on their nerves (even got on my nerves).

Some examples off the top of my head:

1. He became the reason of his first engagement with Mia to be broken up.
2. He once set up his curtains on **fire** after ruining his day.
3. He invited his girlfriend/assistant to move in without his permission and started acting like he owned part of the house when he didn't even pay rent.
4. He acted sickly and dying (Walden's time) and tricked him out of money for his care and comfort.
5. He deliberately tried to break his relations (Walden's) just so he can keep sponging off.

I know not the best examples, but if not in every episode then in every alternate episode he is shown to getting up on their nerves and they just keep on telling him to leave. Why don't they just kick him out? Why put up with such a leach?

Comment: It's a sitcom. Rules of reality do not apply. Also, if there was no strife or conflict there wouldn't be anything moving the "stories" forward.

Comment: You may as well ask "What is funny?" This type of humor keeps the audience coming back every week. Weeks into months, and months into years - 11 years, so far.

Answer (score 3):

Charlie tried to kick out Alan more than once. One or two times he even succeeded (Jake was allowed to stay but Alan took him with him) but Charlie always wanted to have them back. Not to forget there's his bad feeling seeing both Alan and Jake having to stay at their mother's house, which he obviously considers a too big punishment, even for Alan (since he calls her home the portal to hell).

Later on, Walden accepts Alan and allows him to stay after helping him with his (ex-)wife. He once tries to kick out Alan as well, which results in some kind of light heart attack (which reminds Walden of quite a few relatives who died due to him and/or at least close to him), which in the end gets him into welcoming Alan back (who'll promptly try to abuse this fear).

Answer (score 2):

There are different reasons that appeared and disappeared over the seasons.
The first few seasons Charlie was more calm and a normal womanizer, and having Jake in his life was making him feel more uncle, family feelings and he liked it. And Alan was coming with this in the same package. In his words, "I choose him, I got you."

But as the episodes progress, and more resentment appears between them, Charlie stated he would kick his brother out as soon as their mother dies so there will not be "emotional blackmail" from her anymore.

And around the last seasons, Charlie became more of a bitter-evil character, (partly due to Alan) and Alan became more and more of a cheap leech, therefore Charlie kicked him out on several occasions. Once Judith made Alan apologize to come back. And once Alan decided to move out, but then he started begging to come back at the last second.

Overall, the first reason was Charlie having Jake in his life, but later on the show turned this to a part of the comedy, and aired several episodes purely based on how Alan gets his way to stay eventually.

Comment: A nice analysis!

Answer (score 0):

Alan is Charlie's brother, some familial obligation there. Alan is also the father of Jake, and Charlie is somewhat fond of Jake.